# Dropdown list onchange function - update value

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-core, visual-studio-2017

I have a Y/N dropdown list that I would like to update from the view (instead of updating it on the Edit page). For example, if I select "Yes" I will be redirected to the index page which will display "Yes". If I change it to "No" it will show "No". The result will be saved to the database. Basically, I want to call the edit method for the Y/N property on my index page.

What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it :

1. Wrap the dropdown list in a form that will `POST` to the server.

> Not necessarily the `Edit` action... it could be some more specific `UpdateYesNo` action.

2. Listen for `change` events on the dropdown list.
3. Submit the form programmatically from within the `change` event.
4. Handle the request and redirect the client to the appropriate page.

> Since this is a full `POST` request and not an `$.ajax` call we let AspNet Mvc handle the redirection.